# Install php mail service in windows

Tags: php, email, joomla

I am using WAMP server in windows to publish my joomla web site. But I get the error

```
Could not instantiate mail function.
```

I think  mail function or module is not installed on the server. How can I fi it?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `php.ini` file and add:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = put your SMTP server here
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = me@example.com
```

Then restart the apache service.

Comment: I did it but I get the error:

Comment: this error:  Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.googlemail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 4